# How to get hash values when the hash is a private variable within an object?

Tags: ruby, hash

Sorry guys, editing what I am seeing...

I have the following object:

I am in debug mode, so this is what I can see:

```
Object
  |
  |- @hash = Hash (2 elements)
  |    |
  |    |- element_1->value_1
  |    |- element_2->value_2
  |
  |- @raw
  |- @@action
```

I'd like to return the values of `@hash`, specifically I'd like to output the values of `element_1=value_1` and `element_2=value_2`

I've tried the following:

```
Object.attributes  
=> undefined method 'attributes'

Object.instance_variables
```

Returns just the name of `@hash` and `@raw`, but `@hash` is empty, it doesn't contain the expected values of elements and values :S

Any idea how I could get its values?

Comment: your array is not valid.. give a valid one please

Comment: sorry, just edited to put what I can see in the debugger...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After staring in a crystal ball I'd try

```
Object.new.element_array_1.entries
```

EDIT: still unclear after your question's update

- don't know what debug mode you are talking about. It doesn't look
  like an output of standard debug module.
- `instance_variables` method of Object just returns variable names as
  symbols, nothing more so how do you know if `@hash` is empty ?
- if `@hash` is listed between instance variables you can retrieve its value either directly with `Object.instance_variable_get :@hash` or from an initialized instance with `Object.new.instance_variable_get :@hash`

Comment: Thank you so much David, I thought instance_variables was going to return the values, but as you said, this is what returns it:

Object.instance_variable_get :@hash

Many thanks!